# Cakephp 3.6 - Missing Controller Error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am having this error which does not seem to make sense. I am using this plugin: https://github.com/hashmode/cakephp-tinymce-elfinder. I am in need of creating and admin route. However, even though CakePHP sees the plugin, it does not see the Controller within it. I don't see what I am doing wrong.

This is my route for `/admin/elfinder`:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
  $routes->connect('/elfinder', ['plugin' => 'CakephpTinymceElfinder', 'controller' => 'Elfinders', 'action' => 'elfinder']);
});
```

This is the controller/action I am trying to access

https://github.com/hashmode/cakephp-tinymce-elfinder/blob/master/src/Controller/ElfindersController.php

But I get the following error:

```
2018-06-01 15:20:33 Error: [Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException] Controller class Elfinders could not be found.
Request URL: /admin/elfinder
```

It is definitely finding the Plugin. Why can't CakePHP find the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official CookBook you need to configure your prefixed routes in the following way. Hope this helps.

```
Router::plugin('YourPlugin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
        $routes->connect('/:controller');
    });
});
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Some time ago I wrote a plugin for my personal needs. I needed to bind its controllers to the `/shop` and `/shop/api` URLs. I managed to do it like this

```
Router::scope('/shop',['plugin'=>'MyPlugin'] ,function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->prefix('api', function($routes) {
        $routes->extensions(['json']);
        $routes->connect('/:controller');

        $routes->resources('Categories');
        $routes->resources('Products');
        $routes->resources('Prices');
        $routes->resources('Pricetypes');
    });

    $routes->connect('/:controller');
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

Comment: Your answer is legit and provides some good examples. I will accept this as a good answer to deal and setup CakePHP routes, however, my issue was of my own doing. The 3rd Party Plugin did not have an admin controller tha fitted how my applications was setup. `src/Controller/Admin/MyControllers.php`. Something like that!